# App store still supporting Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, app-store

Does anyone know if it's still possible to upload apps to the app store written for iOS 6 in Xcode 4?
I can't uppgraderar to Mac OS 10.8.4, which mean I can't upgrade to Xcode 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes . I have submit app to appstore . and app is live now

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can still use Xcode 4 to submit applications to the store written for iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit apps through Xcode 4.x. But when Apple reviews your App your app might possibly get rejected by Apple as they review app on different devices and iOS versions. So, your app might not work correctly on iOS 7 devices due to changes in built-in default controls like UIAlertView and other changes etc.

I also submitted app few day ago and it was rejected by Apple as they received bugs while testing on iPhone 5, iOS 7. So, I have to move to Mac OS X 10.8.4 and Xcode 5 to see what's happening on iOS 7 device.

Comment: Users having iOS 7 will be able to download and use your app.